# Displaying errors when uploading files PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

im making a user profile edit page and i have added a profile pic upload option but it does not show error message when file size is above limit

```
if(isset($_POST["submits"]))
{
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_maxsize=2000000;
if(!($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']==""))
{
    $target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") 
    {
        $_SESSION['uperr']="Please select an image file (.jpg, .jpeg & .png)";
        header('Location: http://localhost/VULCAN/dashboard.php?q=setting');
    }
    else
    {
        if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] < $target_maxsize)
        {
            if(file_exists($target_file))
            {
                $_SESSION['uperr']="File Already Exists!";
                header('Location: http://localhost/VULCAN/dashboard.php?q=setting');
            }
            else
            {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file))
                {
                $_SESSION['uperr']="File has been uploaded successfully!";
                header('Location: http://localhost/VULCAN/dashboard.php?q=setting');
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['uperr']="File could not be uploaded!";
                    header('Location: http://localhost/VULCAN/dashboard.php?q=setting');    
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['uperr']="File is too large!";
            header('Location: http://localhost/VULCAN/dashboard.php?q=setting');
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['uperr']="Please select a file first!";
    header('Location: http://localhost/VULCAN/dashboard.php?q=setting');
}
}
```

this is what i use for displaying error message if any

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['uperr'])/*$sesfilerr!=""*/)
{
    ?><script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['uperr']; ?>");
        });
        </script><?php
unset($_SESSION['uperr']);
}
?>
</body>
```

help anybody?
also when i refresh the page the error message is displayed again. anything to prevent this?

Comment: _sidenote:_ do not hardcode the domain, especially 'localhost', use relative paths.

Comment: did you start the session (in second file)?

Comment: _"it does not show error message"_ versus _"the error message is displayed again"_ ?

Comment: did include jquery in the second file? (or give it a try without the document.ready, you don't need it there)

Comment: aaaand here `alert("<?php echo $sesfilerr; ?>")` $sesfilerr is undefined. You want `alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['uperr']; ?>")`, right?

Comment: using relative paths does not seems to work for me.

Comment: i did not start session in 2nd file

Comment: _another sidenote_: In this case I'd recommend to avoid nesting all the ifs. Turn the logic around (`if( ! isset($_POST["submits"]))`) to eliminate all the else cases.

Comment: _"i did not start session in 2nd file"_ - you 'd have to to make it work then!

Comment: more like the "file could not be uploaded" is shown

Comment: yes its $_SESSION['uperr'] there corrected it

Comment: "In this case I'd recommend to avoid nesting all the ifs. Turn the logic around (if( ! isset($_POST["submits"]))) to eliminate all the else cases." - but then if i click upload with no file selected it shows error

Comment: of course you'd have to restructure the codeblocks then. Keep that in mind for later, it was just a sidenote to make the code easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['uperr']))
    {
        ?><script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['uperr']; ?>");
            });
            </script><?php
        unset($_SESSION['uperr']);
        $_SESSION['sett']=1;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i already tried this. when i do this alert box is not displayed at all